# Heroku node.js app runs locally but crashes remotely

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a node.js application which is **not a web application**. 
Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "myapp-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "MyApp PubNub backend",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "backend"
  ],
  "author": "Pete Gu",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "pubnub": "^4.3.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node" : "6.9.2"
  }
}
```

Contents of `Procfile`:

```
app: node app.js
```

It runs when I run `heroku local`. However, after pushing the code and checking logs with `heroku logs` I see this:

```
2016-12-22T06:07:01.276053+00:00 app[api]: Deploy fb193d3 by user xxxxx@xxxx.com
2016-12-22T06:07:01.477131+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-12-22T06:07:01.477136+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-12-22T06:07:01.276053+00:00 app[api]: Release v13 created by user gpeetonn@gmail.com
2016-12-22T06:07:01.507095+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-12-22T06:07:02.759643+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-12-22T06:07:06.003266+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-12-22T06:07:06.016232+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-12-22T06:07:06.017114+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-12-22T06:07:05.872484+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
2016-12-22T06:07:05.872909+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-12-22T06:07:05.873173+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.9.2
2016-12-22T06:07:05.873421+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
2016-12-22T06:07:05.877486+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2016-12-22T06:07:05.875800+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-12-22T06:07:05.877738+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-12-22T06:07:05.877884+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2016-12-22T06:07:05.878031+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2016-12-22T06:07:05.892349+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-12-22T06:07:05.892997+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-12-22T06:07:05.892655+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-12-22T06:07:07.532860+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-12-22T06:07:10.603753+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
2016-12-22T06:07:10.604065+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-12-22T06:07:10.604260+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.9.2
2016-12-22T06:07:10.604476+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
2016-12-22T06:07:10.606525+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-12-22T06:07:10.607621+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2016-12-22T06:07:10.607822+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-12-22T06:07:10.607900+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2016-12-22T06:07:10.607998+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2016-12-22T06:07:10.618207+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-12-22T06:07:10.618415+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-12-22T06:07:10.618645+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-12-22T06:07:10.718608+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-12-22T06:07:10.710362+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

...which completely doesn't make sense to me - why heroku tries to launch app using `npm start` instead of reading `Procfile`?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku seems to be trying to start a web dyno, and doesn't seem to know about your Procfile.

Are you sure you added your Procfile to your git repo?

Anyway, try this:

```
heroku ps:scale web=0
heroku ps:scale app=1
```

You could also add  "start": "node app.js" in the "scripts" section of your package.json.

Comment: the issue turned out to be that my "app" dyno was turned off in the web dashboard and heroku was trying to launch default "web" dyno which doesn't apply to my app. so I just turned it on.

Comment: Which is exactly what I suggested that you try with the heroku ps:scale commands.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the error **missing script: start** So you need to add

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node bin/xxx" //your main file name
}
```

add this to your package.json.

Comment: nope, I have Procfile, so heroku shouldn't be trying to launch that